# format/Erase Equivalence Disk Utility and Terminal Command diskutil

Tags: terminal, disk-utility, disk-format, diskutil

What is the `diskutil` equivalence from **Disk Utility** of

- Format/Erase with Format `MS-DOS(FAT)` and `Scheme GUID Partition Map`.
- Format/Erase with Format `MS-DOS(FAT)` and `Scheme Master Boot Record`.

In other words how do format/erase a disk with Console/Terminal?

Comment: The Terminal command `man diskutil` is your friend. Take some time to get to know the `man` pages

Comment: @chepe lucho @Allan Of course, diskutil is the tool of choice. In this context it makes sense to have a look at the `asr` and `hdiutil` tools as well. If you are not familiar with `man` and the `less`pager it makes use of by default, consider reading the documentation texts on the ss64 site, see https://ss64.com/osx/ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent commands are given below.

```
diskutil eraseDisk MS-DOS GPT diskX
diskutil eraseDisk MS-DOS MBR diskX
```

Where `diskX` is the identifier for the drive. The value of `X` needs to be replaced with a integer of `0` or higher. The command `diskutil list` will list all the current disk identifiers. The command `diskutil listfilesystems` will list the available formats.